# ASP.NET panel DefaultButton event fires only once?

Tags: asp.net, panel

For a panel with one textbox and one button which is its default button, the DefaultButton event fires only once as editing textbox details again and pressing enter, event doesn't fire.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlNewFolderDetails" DefaultButton="btnAddFolder">
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFolderHeader" Text="New Folder Name" CssClass="label" />
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFolderName" ToolTip="Folder Name" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddFolder" OnClick="btnAddFolder_Click" Text="Add" />
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds to me like your DefaultButton is firing on the first click of an enter button, but if the button is clicked again the event doesn't fire. 
If so, is the second event failing after the server has responded, or before?

Answer (score 0):

> For a panel with one textbox and one button which is its default button, the DefaultButton event fires only once as editing textbox details again and pressing enter, event doesn't fire.

What do you mean "the DefaultButton event"? There isn't an event as such, .NET inserts some HTML that will associate the TextBox with the Button when Enter is pressed, it is not related to the click's of a button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UpdatePanels`, add this in `btnAddFolder_Click`:

```
txtFolderName.Focus();
```

I had the same problem, and setting focus on the textbox seems to be a workaround that works for me.